# Doctrine Query - Get sub objects

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

I am using Doctrine ORM in my Laravel Project. I have three tables :

- Smi
- Device Group
- Device

Each device has a device group, and each device group has a smi.
What I want to do with Doctrine is to query all groups and get their devices and their smi.

Here is my query in PHP (from the repository) :

```
   $results = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('dg')
            ->from($this->_entityName, 'dg')
            ->innerJoin('dg.smi_enterprise_code', 'sec')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Here are the tables structure :

**Table device_group :**

[image: Table devicegroup]

Each device group has one smi_enterprise_code (via smi_enterprise_code_id)

**Table smi_enterprise_code:**

[image: Table smienterprisecode]

**Table device :**

[image: Table device]

These tables were created using artisan with theses classes :

SmiEnterpriseCode.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Entities;
    
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    
    /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repositories\SmiEnterpriseCode")
 * @ORM\Table(name="smi_enterprise_code")
 */
class SmiEnterpriseCode extends SCAPBaseModel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="code")
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * One SmiEnterpriseCode has Many DeviceGroup
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\DeviceGroup", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="smi_enterprise_code")
     */
    protected $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function getIana()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function getVendor()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }

    public function addGroup(DeviceGroup $group)
    {
        $this->groups->add($group);
        $group->setSmi($this);
    }
```

DeviceGroup.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Entities;
    
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    
    /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repositories\DeviceGroup")
 * @ORM\Table(name="device_group")
 */
class DeviceGroup extends SCAPBaseModel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="oid", length=127)
     */
    protected $oid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="hash", length=127)
     */
    protected $hash;

    /**
     * Many DeviceGroup have one SmiEnterpriseCode
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entities\SmiEnterpriseCode", inversedBy="groups")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="smi_enterprise_code_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $smi_enterprise_code;

    /**
     * One DeviceGroup has Many Device
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\Device", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="device_group")
     */
    protected $devices;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->devices = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function setSmi(SmiEnterpriseCode $smi)
    {
        $this->smi_enterprise_code = $smi;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "active" => $this->active,
            "oid" => $this->oid,
            "name" => $this->name,
            "iana" => $this->smi_enterprise_code->getIana(),
            "vendor" => $this->smi_enterprise_code->getVendor(),
            "created_at" => parent::formatTimestamp($this->date_created),
            "updated_at" => parent::formatTimestamp($this->timestamp)
        ];
    }


}
```

For now I just want to access to the SMI of the groups, I will deal with the devices later.

NB : the classes extend from a superclass which includes common fields such as id, timestamp...

This is what I get at the moment :

[image: What I get]

As you can see the values are null whereas I created entries in the database (and anyway I cant have a device group without a SMI).

Do you see what the problem is ?

Thanking you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the causes of my problem.

I just had to run **php artisan doctrine:generate:entities** in order to get rid of it.

Regards,